How can I install an application in Ubuntu Server and ensure only it runs in the GUI?
I want to make a project. These are the materials I will use in my project.

Industrial HMI All-in-one Touch Display For Raspberry Pi 5, Options For 8inch / 10.1inch, Supports Dual 4K HDMI Output, 10-point Touch, Optical Bonding, Aluminum Alloy Case
Raspberry Pi 5
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

I designed a screen and turned it into an executable file. What I want to do is to make this screen work as soon as Ubuntu is started and the user cannot close this screen in any way. And only this application works in the GUI section of Ubuntu, I do not need other programs.
In short, can I install it as Ubuntu Server 20.04 and ensure that there is a GUI only in the program part I wrote with QT?
If it is something that can be done, how can I do it or what should I research?
Is there an easier way for me to do this?

You firstly mention Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (or the 2020-April release; which pre-dates the raspberry pi 5!) , but then mention Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  Your details thus contradict, so I suggest you re-read & correct or explain what you're using as you've listed two different releases.

if all you want is to run your application then the rest of the windowing system seems superfluous. QT programs can draw directly to the framebuffer: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html

Yes. You can use a server or the Rasbian OS lite - both do not have any desktop. However you'll need to install XServer or ensure that your code will run on the framebuffer.
With XServer you'll need to startx (eg in .bash_profile) and your application.
Basic steps:
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg-video-all \
    xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-core xinit x11-xserver-utils unclutter

In /home/<your user>/.bash_profileadd:
if [ -z $DISPLAY ] && [ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]
then
    startx
fi

To tell X what to start you need to create and write into .xinitrc:
#!/usr/bin/env sh
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank

unclutter & <name of your program>

I've done this on a pi-os lite with a chrome-browser in kiosk mode. There are many other ways to it - just google "pi as kiosk"
Make sure you can log in without password
